# Primes Involved in GCD

Tags: prime-numbers

If p is a prime number, prove that gcd(p, (p-1)!) = 1

So, I've tried using the fact that 1 = px + (p-1)!y, where x,y are integers, but from there I'm stuck and don't really know how to work with the factorial term.

Comment: $\gcd(p, (p-1)!)$ is in particular a divisor of $p$. That reduces the possibilities considerably.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is prime, $d:=\gcd(p, (p-1)!) $ is a divisor of $p$. It is then $p$ or 1.

If it is $d=p$, $p = d|(p-1)!$ which means that $p$ appears in the prime decomposition of
$(p-1)! = 1\times 2\times \dots \times (p-1)$.

But the biggest prime factor of $(p-1)!$, a product made with factors $<p$, is $<p$ as well.
This a contradiction.

---

Note that the other implication is also true:

if $\gcd(p, (p-1)!) = 1$ then the biggest prime factor of $p$ is none of $1,2\dots (p-1)$, then it is $p$. Then $p$ is prime.